# how to keep dropdown item selected in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am newbie to angularjs and made a demo on dropdown menu,I have make it successfully and it is working fine,But now i want to keep last selected item when we open it again,My code is as below,can anybuddy please help me to solve this issue?

**html**

```
   <span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height" style="border: none; padding: 0">
                <i  class="ion-android-more-vertical" dropdown-disabled="isDropdownDisabled" style="font-size: 26px; margin: 0; padding: 0 17px 0 12px;" dropdown-menu="ddMenuOptions" dropdown-model="ddMenuSelected" dropdown-disabled="dropdownsDisabled"></i>  

            </span>
```

**js**

```
 $scope.ddMenuOptions = [
            {
                text: 'Featured',
                code: 'F'
//      divider: true
            }, {
                text: 'Name (A-Z)',
                code: 'A'
//      divider: true
            }, {
                text: 'Rating',
                code: 'M'
//      divider: true
            }, {
                text: ' Most Popular',
                code: 'MP'
//      divider: true
            }
        ];

        $scope.ddMenuSelected = {
        };

        $scope.$watch("ddMenuSelected", function(newValue, oldValue) {

            $scope.selectedItem = newValue;
            var result = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");
            var wrappedResult = angular.element(result);
            // alert("Selected" + wrappedResult);
            // wrappedResult.removeClass('active');
            wrappedResult.addClass('activated');
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {

                console.log("=========" + $scope.ddMenuSelected.code);
                //window.reload(true);
                $rootScope.ddMenuOptions = false;
// $scope.ddMenuOptions=false;
                Content = ' ';
                if (noNetwork == false) {

                    reload();
                } else {

                    ons.notification.alert({message: 'We are unable to process, please check your internet connection.',
                        callback: function(idx) {
                            switch (idx) {
                                case 0:
                                    gallery.popPage();

                                    break;

                            }
                        }});
                }
            }


        });
```

Comment: what issue? Please explain the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Michael-i want to keep item as "selected" when i again open dropdown menu.

Comment: yes, but what IS the issue you struggle with? What is not working? Please describe the problem you have. I don't see any issue. I just see a few code fragments.

Comment: this is not an issue,I want to add this in my existing code.

Comment: i don't really know how to tell that you have to describe your problem. `it is not working` is not helping!! tell us what you did and which part is not working

Comment: @Michael-Ok friend,I am explain you,i am having a dropdown menu with 4 listitems,now i want to show item "selected",which is selected previously when i again open the dropdown menu ,and code for dropdown i already displayed in my question.please save me

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the `selectedItem` somewhere where it survives. Outside the controller you typically store it in a `service` or the `rootScope`.

When initializing the controller again you set the old value of `selectedItem` to `ddMenuSelected`.

for example:

```
$scope.ddMenuSelected = $rootScope.selectedItem;
```

I don't know what you mean by **open it again** and what you do in the **reload()** function. But a typically angular application is a one-page-application should not reload the page/application. This would be a terrible design issue, but in that case you have to store the value somewhere, where it can survive. Either you store it on the server side or you store it in the HTML5 `localStore`.

See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp and http://www.ellipsetours.com/Demos/storage/

Comment: Hello,Thank you for your answer michael,I am explaining you here,What this popup doing is,My **reload** function is making a call to http request to load data,And i have make a dropdown menu for sorting this data purpose,now hope you got what i have made..:)

Comment: open it again means its a dropdown,so whenever we click toggle[ button we can open a dropdown as many times as we want,are you getting me?

Comment: Then set the `$scope.ddMenuSelected` value to the previous selection. If you don't initialize it, it won't show the previous value. Where exactly is the problem?